# import const from function in another file javascript

Tags: javascript

How i can import const from function in another file which is export default.

Here is address.js(where is const which i wanna get):

```
export default function addressUrl () {
  const email = Math.random().toString(25).substring(5) + '@xyz.com';
  return `grabiv/${md5(email)}`;
}
```

and

output.js (where i want to use this const from address.js)

```
import {email} from '../address;

export function gravatarImage (window) {
    document.getElementById("mail").innerText = email
}
```

Maybe is other way to solve this fault. when I want write "export" before const then I've got error.

Comment: declare email outside of export default as `export const email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to separate it out from inside the function

***Edit From John's comment*** :since its the case of generating random emails ,make it a `function` to return the `random emails` and use `export`

```
//address.js
export const email =()=> Math.random().toString(25).substring(5) + '@xyz.com'
export default function addressUrl (emailValue) {
  return `grabiv/${md5(emailValue)}`;
}
```

and then

```
//output.js 
//edit from awarrier's comment
import addressUrl,{email} from '../address;
export function gravatarImage (window) {
    document.getElementById("mail").innerText = email()
}
```

Comment: It should be `import addressUrl, { email } from '../address';` as `addressUrl` is a default export

Comment: thanks for adding the point.Let me test it and update accordingly.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this will only generate one random number and use it every time the function is called, whereas the original will generate a different number every time.

Comment: Yes what you have is said. I have made edits to my answer.

Comment: That's the way I expected. Thanks You very much !

Answer (score 2):

Change your first file with the function so that you can define the variable at the module level and export it:

```
let email;

export default function addressUrl () {
  email = Math.random().toString(25).substring(5) + '@xyz.com';
  return `grabiv/${md5(email)}`;
}

export email;
```

Note that I'm assuming you want the value of `email` to be set by the function `addressUrl` (so that if you call the function multiple times, a new email will be randomly generated each time, rather than using one value the whole time), so as mentioned in the comments, the value will be `undefined` until this function is called

Comment: Doesn't this mean that unless he calls `addressUrl`, `email` will be undefined?

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza yes, but that would be the case regardless

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza I'm assuming in this situation that `email` should be newly generated each time the function is called